# Increasing all elements by integer x in O(n) in a program possibility?

Tags: c++, integer

So I have stumbled upon a problem to solve:

I need to create a data structure that will have a set of integers.
It needs to have methods:
The class is named:

> class structure

methods:

> void structure::new(); //creates an empty set
>
> void structure::insert(int x); //inserts an integer x into the set
>
> bool structure::isElement(int x); //checks if x is in the set
>
> void structure::increaseBy(int x); // increases all elements in set by x

I guess this one is a homework question.

But i just want an opinion what data structure is the best to use in this implementation.

And how can i create the last method that would increase all elements by x in O(1) times, at first it seems like impossible.
Even if there are some c++ operators that have a functionality like that, wouldn't they have the same complexity?

I mean i could use a vector, array, even some linked list, set or similar structures.

So the problems isn't with first three methods, they are pretty easy to do, and also it is okay to use O(n) for the last one, but it's not "full points" unless it's O(1) time complexity. So is there a way to do it? Any hints would be helpful, and also I apologize if i made a mistake in creating this question it's my first time posting in stackoverflow.com, i was only using/posting math.stackexchange.com until now, so any advice would be appreciated as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless all the elements were references to a single number, you'll have to iterate the entire list to increase each element. Then it doesn't really matter what structure you choose since they'll all be O(n) for iteration anyway. If you want `isElement` to be as efficient as possible though, use a Set implementation, which the instructions seem to want you to use anyway.

Comment: Are these all the methods that you need to implement? What are the requirements of the first few operations?

Comment: This is a "think outside the box" question. Hint: you don't need to modify a single element.

Comment: O(1) for new, O(logn) for insert O(n) for last two and bonus for the last one if O(1). 
So <set> is going to be the way to go?

Comment: structure::new is going to be really hard to implement

Comment: @Ap31  Did u use sarcasm?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife I'm going to guess, ya, that's sarcasm

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife to some extent I did, sorry. But it will be hard to implement, `new` being a keyword and all

Comment: I just translated from my native language to english, so it's not really going to pose a problem as "nov"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation

```
class structure
{
public:
    void insert(int x) {ls.push_front(x - offset);}
    bool isElement(int x) {return std::find(ls.begin(), ls.end(), x - offset) != ls.end();}
    void increaseBy(int x) {offset += x;}
private:
    int offset = 0;
    std::list<int> ls;
};
```

This is

- O(1) for `insert`
- O(n) for `isElement`
- O(1) for `increaseBy`

Comment: Using `std::set` instead of `std::list` to have `O(log N)`/`O(logN)`/`O(1)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I was thinking about something concerning lists before this and that's the first thing that popped into my mind when I see the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Let's add `addedSum` member to your class:

```
template<typename Set> struct setWithInc {
    Set container;
    int addedSum;

    setWithInc() : addedSum(0) {}

    bool isElement(int x) {
        return container.find(x - addedSum) != container.end();
    }

    void insert(int x) {
        container.insert(x - addedSum);
    }

    void increaseBy(int x) {
        addedSum += x;
    }
};
```